# Set HTTP header to all requests on Postman by default

Tags: http, postman, http-headers

How to configure **Postman** to send `Content-Type: application/json` header on every request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following solution in [a blogpost post](https://www.baeldung.com/postman-add-headers-pre-request) which consists of adding a pre-request script to my **collections/folder/request**.

```js
pm.request.headers.add({
    key: "Accept",
    value: "application/json"
});
```